# Is PyCharm able to automatically select interpreter according to the `.python-version` file?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, interpreter, pyenv

Although I can manually choose virtual env created by `pyenv` in the `preferences > project foo > Project interpreter`; I am curious that is `PyCharm` able to automatically use interpreter according to the `.python-version` file during project startup?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20638 (thumbs up near the issue title)

Comment: thank you so much @user2235698 :)  I just did the thump-up!